# OAuth2 flow for Desktop Applications

Tags: oauth-2.0

Which oauth 2.0 flow should I use if I'm developing a C# Desktop Application?

Generally, I'm using this diagram in order to take a decision:

[image]

However, I don't quite figure out what's a Desktop App...

Answer (score 0):

Desktop apps fall under the category "Native Apps" together with mobile apps; they're "rich" apps that are specifically built to run on a particular operating system, as opposed to web applications that run in a generic web browser on any platform.

Comment: Is there any example over there showing how to handle this flow in a .net desktop application?